# Not Unique values in only one table in Cascading Dropdown list AjaxToolkit .NET Framework 4.0 ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, combobox, drop-down-menu

Question about the cascading dropdown list / comboboxes / drop down lists or however you wanna call them. The ones in the AjaxToolkit in .NET 4.0 using IIS 6.

Is it possible to use a table that looks like this:

ProjectID(UniqueKey int) ProjectNumber(string) ProjectSubNumber(string) ProjectTitle(string)

and with those cascading dropdowns get the data cascaded. I get an error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints

The question is, how to tell the webmethod that I know what I'm doing and I still wanna use those projectNumbers as values and text in the parent dropdown list and get a subnumber from it which is usually going to be copied throughout the subnumber column
(meaning ie.:

- projectNumber 1120 subNo 00,
- projectNumber 1120 subNo 01,
- projectNumber 1121 subNo 00,

.... and so on....)

Help!

I then want to get a project title displayed in a text box (with a `dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged method`) .